# DAY function does not work as expected in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

I have a issue with Day function;

I am extracting date from text string and storing it in a column; say Sep 30, or Sep 23; I want to see DAY of this date and put it in next column; something like this

```
Sep 23 Tuesday  
Sep 30 Sunday
```

Formula used for column B is `=day(a1+1)` because `=day(A1)` gives me previous day; like Sept 30 gives me Saturday.

But `A1+1` works correct for second row; Sunday, but fails for first row; Tuesday. Sept 23 was Wednesday.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that your dates are from a different year than the one you are expecting.

Use the formula bar to check the complete data value and correct the them as necessary.